# Search in xml using xpath in postgresql db

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have a database in Postgresql where I put some documents written in xml.
I want to search twrough them using XPath, but my code is not working.
The document are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        ....
        <revisionDesc>
            <listChange>
                <change when="2017-01-11+01:00" who="person"/>
            </listChange>
        </revisionDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    ...
</TEI>
```

I'm trying to get the when attribute of the change element.
My code so far:

```
SELECT 

xpath('TEI/n:teiHeader/n:revisionDesc/n:listChange/n:change[@when]/text()',

xml_document , '{{n,http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}}') 

FROM xml_table where xml_id = 5;
```

It gives me empty result like this: {} and I don't understand why

Comment: 1. `TEI` element is also in default namespace. Use prefix for it as well : `n:TEI/.....`. 2. `change` element doesn't have inner text so `/text()` won't find anything, and I don't know what you actually want to get from `change` element

Comment: The value of the when attribute, in the example 2017-01-11+01:00

Comment: In that case, replace `/text()` with `/@when`

Comment: 'n:TEI/n:teiHeader/n:revisionDesc/n:listChange/n:change/@when' and 'n:TEI/n:teiHeader/n:revisionDesc/n:listChange/n:change[@when]/@when' give the same result {}, did I miss something?

Comment: @tina prepend them with `/` to denote that `n:TEI` is you root element -- or ommit `n:TEI` completely, because `xpath()` will search for results relative to the root element (in `xpath` terms, that is the current node).

Comment: That solved it, if you answer the question I will give you best answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend your `xpath` query with `/` if you want to reference the root element. Or, you could ommit `n:TEI`, because the `xpath()` function will search for results relative to the root element (in `xpath` terms, that is the current node).

I.e. these `xpath` queries will find the `when` attributes' values:

```
/n:TEI/n:teiHeader/n:revisionDesc/n:listChange/n:change/@when
n:teiHeader/n:revisionDesc/n:listChange/n:change/@when
```